# Generate new column as difference of nth and n-1th elements

Tags: r

Hello I have the following dataset:

```
year<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
total<-c(4462,8233,8233,8631,8631,9016,9016,9420,9494)
df<-data.frame(year,total)
```

I need to compute a third column from the difference of n and n-1 elements in the second column:

```
new<-c(4462,3771,0,398,0,385,0,404,74)
```

So that the result for the first element is for instance 8233-4462 = 3771; second element 8233 - 8233 = 0, etc.

How could I do this? The final result should be:

```
df<-data.frame(year,total,new)
```

Comment: `diff(total)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` option using `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(new = (total-lag(total)),
         new = coalesce(new, total))
```

Output:

```
  year total  new
1    0  4462 4462
2    1  8233 3771
3    2  8233    0
4    3  8631  398
5    4  8631    0
6    5  9016  385
7    6  9016    0
8    7  9420  404
9    8  9494   74
```

Comment: This is also an interesting solution, thanks!

Comment: Sorry did not saw your `lag` solution. If you want I can delete mine. But I think it is interesting because of the `default` argument. What do you think?

Comment: @TarJae, Its no problem! I also upvoted your approach because of the nice `default` argument!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `diff`

```
> transform(df, new = diff(c(0,total)))
  year total  new
1    0  4462 4462
2    1  8233 3771
3    2  8233    0
4    3  8631  398
5    4  8631    0
6    5  9016  385
7    6  9016    0
8    7  9420  404
9    8  9494   74
```

Comment: That's neat, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We could use `lag()`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = total-lag(total, default = total[1]+total[1]*-1))
```

```
  year total  new
1    0  4462 4462
2    1  8233 3771
3    2  8233    0
4    3  8631  398
5    4  8631    0
6    5  9016  385
7    6  9016    0
8    7  9420  404
9    8  9494   74
```